# jquery ajax not receiving node.js response properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, passport.js

Client side code:

```
  for(var i =0; i < 1; i++) {
    void function(item) {
        alert(item);
        $.ajax({
          url : "/documents/ajax/" + item,
          dataType : "text",
          success : function(data) {
            alert("data");
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error: ' + error.message);
          }
        });
    }(featuredItems.eq(i).text().trim());
  }
```

Node.js code:

```
app.get('/documents/ajax/:id.:format?', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Request Received");
  res.send("Response");
  res.end();

});
```

With this code I am not able to receive the response on client side.

If I do a ctrl-c on my node server, then success alert is popped up.

Please help/

UPDATE:

If I comment out following lines then I receive response properly:

```
//  app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret_key'}));
//  app.use(passport.initialize());
//  app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: You could try alerting your data and not the string "data" for one :) Also, could you provide more of your server code?

Comment: I just wanted to see if the success handler is called. Initially I was trying alert(data), It didnt work I thought may be somwthing wrong with data itself

Comment: In that case it sounds like you have some blocking code in your node.js code (that is, response.end is not ending the response). Could you post more of that? What about accessing the URL directly without a jQuery ajax request, does that work?

Comment: Other than what I posted above I dont have code in my ajax handler in node server. Those are the last two line. Somehow res.end() is not ending the response. I have posted the entire ajax handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using old style of $.ajax; read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

else no post/get method.

If you think you have problem with express, just create new clear app from terminal for **testing**: `express -s myapp`

here's my $.ajax code:

```
$('.form-2').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
            data.email = $('#email').val().toLowerCase();
            data.pass = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({ url: '/login'
               , type: 'POST'
               , data: JSON.stringify(data)
               , contentType: 'application/json'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if (data.access == 'logged') ...
            });
});
```

server:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ access: 'logged' });
});
```